# How can I count alphabet characters efficiently?

Tags: c++

I initialized an array of characters, to put all uppercase and lowercase alphabets.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    char c;
    int cnt = 0;
    cout << "Enter 0 to view the results " << endl;
    char arr[52] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    while (1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            cin >> c;
            if (c == arr[i]){
                cnt++;
            }
            else if (c == '0'){
                break;
            }
            else{
                cout << "Please enter only characters!" << endl;
            }
        }
        if (c == '0')
            break;
    }
    cout << cnt << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I know that this code is inefficient.

- How to write this code without `break;`?
- If there's a better way to do that without using array, please mention it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code review requests belong to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your solution is wrong in many ways, not inefficient.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the program does.

Comment: presence of `arr` array tells that you got no clue what ASCII is

Comment: @liliscent Why is it wrong?

Comment: @LukeCholes Look at your `for` loop carefully

Comment: See an 'ASCII Table' (eg. http://www.asciitable.com/) and note the relationship between characters. How may this be utilized here? (ASCII is *very* English-centric.)

Comment: @RSahu The programs counts how many alphabetical letters are entered by the user, if he entered '0' the program will print the count of how many alphabetical letters he entered.

Comment: Have you looked at [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha)?

Comment: @liliscent I see no problem in the for loop, could you mention the problem please?

Comment: You have an array of 52 elements, yet you try to access up to the 100000000th element

Comment: @user2864740 -- there is no need to hardcode ASCII for the problem that seems to underly this question.

Comment: @PeteBecker If it were "an" answer, I'd have written An Answer. Regardless of the abstraction, the general concept/knowledge seems .. unknown .. by the OP.

Comment: @user2864740 -- I didn't suggest that you were proposing an answer. ASCII has nothing to do with the question, and talking about (or even thinking about) the relationship between characters in ASCII tables is just plain wrong.

Comment: @PeteBecker Regardless of the numerous other issues (that exist but *were not asked*), the OP very clearly **asks** "If there's a better way to do that without using array, please mention it." - Hence I mention the relationship for the OPs *information gain*. To say "is just plain wrong" is a value judgement rejecting the *ask*.

Answer (score 0):

OP's question is very unclear but what I have understood from the comments is OP trying to find a simpler/similar way of counting someone's input for lowercase/upperCase alphabets and keep doing so until the user enters in a 0, I looked online and i found a better way and did some adjustments, it is pretty straight forward, here it is below.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
 {
    string s = "TEST";
    while(s != "0"){    
        cout << " Enter text: ";
        getline(cin, s);
        size_t count_alpha = count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), 
            [](unsigned char ch) { return isalpha(ch); });
        cout << "Alphabets: " << (  count_alpha)<<endl ;
    }
}
```